# Use brackets in json output

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion

Here is the output that I have right now:-

```
{"name":"a","path":"a","type":"folder","items":{"name":"b","path":"a/b","type":"folder","items":{"name":"c.docx","path":"a/b/c.docx","type":"file","size":"20"}}}
```

and I want to add bracket in the items part.So it would be like

```
{"name":"a", "path":"a", "type":"folder", "items":[{"name":"b", "path":"a/b", "type":"folder", "items":[{"name":"c.docx", "path":"a/b/c.docx", "type":"file", "size":"20"} ] }]}
```

Here is the code that I'm using

```
$strings='a/b/c.docx';
$items = explode('/', $strings);
$num = count($items)-1;
$root= array();
$cur = &$root;
$temp = array();
$v='';
foreach($items as $keys => $value) {
   $v = $v.$value;
   $temp = array(   "name" => $value,  "path"=>$v,  "type" => "folder",    "items" => "");
   if($keys == $num){ 
      $temp = array( "name" => $value, "path"=>$v, "type" => "file", "size" => "20"); 
   }
   $v= $v.'/';
   if($keys==0) {
       $cur = $temp;
   }
   else
   {
       $cur['items'] = $temp; 
       $cur = &$cur['items'];
   }
}
echo json_encode($root,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Where am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you test it with `$cur['items'] = array($temp);`?

Comment: change `$cur['items'] = $temp; ` to `$cur['items'][] = $temp; `

Comment: @meyer9 it doesn't work the way that I want.It would make a 2 index array

Comment: @SahilGulati It won't work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer‘s working on arrays, I put comments in the code to explain how it works:

```
<?php
namespace JsonTest;
$strings='a/b/c.docx';

// use namespaced function to avoid polluting global scope
/**
 * @param string $path The path to be processed
 * @return string The JSON structure
 */
function jsonify($path)
{
    // Build file information first in desired format
    $fileInfo = [
        'name' => basename($path), // 'c.docx'
        'path' => $path, // 'a/b/c.docx'
        'type' => 'file', // fixed value
        'size' => '20', // fixed??
    ];

    // Transform ['a', 'b'] to ['a', 'a/b']
    $pathStack = [];
    // Don‘t use result of array_reduce, pass &$pathStack by reference instead
    array_reduce(
        explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, dirname($path)),  // ['a', 'b']
        function($carry, $dir) use (&$pathStack)  {
            $carry []= $dir;
            $pathStack []= implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $carry);
            return $carry;
        }, 
        []
    );

    // Build result from $pathStack and $fileInfo
    $result = array_reduce(
        array_reverse($pathStack), // reverse to begin in nested path
        function($items, $pathHere) {
            return [
                "name" => basename($pathHere), // 1: 'b', 2: 'a'
                "path" => $pathHere, // 1: 'a/b', 2: 'a'
                "type" => 'folder', // fixed
                'items' => [$items], // This is what was missing in the end, wrapping array around items
            ];
        }, 
        $fileInfo // use built $fileInfo for initial $items
    );

    return json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}

echo jsonify($strings);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the code is not correct.The first value of the array is folder 'a' but your code is showing b Here is the output: {"name":"b","path":"a/b","type":"folder","items":[{"name":"c.docx","path":"a/b/c.docx","type":"file","size":"20"}]}

Comment: It only shows the last two strings separated by slash

Comment: Well, that‘s strange. What‘s your PHP version? Mine is `v7.0.17-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` and it works as supposed.

Comment: Ah, I put `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` by habit - if you‘re running Windows that might resolve to `\\`. Suggest you try to replace the constant by '/'.

Comment: I changed the  `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to `/` and It worked flawlessly.Thank you very much.